# UInt8Array constructor does not use buffer in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I'm writing a nodejs (v13.9.0) app that does some byte-by-byte analysis of a stream.

However, when I go create a `UInt8Array` of an existing `Buffer`, it does not pick up the supplied buffer

```
let buffer = Buffer.alloc(72);
let allbytes = new Uint8Array(buffer,0);
console.log(allbytes); // [0,0,0,0,....

let version = new Uint8Array(buffer,2,1);
console.log(version.length); // 72 <-- was expecting `1`
console.log(version); // [0,0,0,0,....
version[0] = 1;
console.log(version); // [1,0,0,0,....
console.log(allbytes); // [0,0,0,0,.... <-- was expecting [0,0,1,0,...
```

I'm expecting `allbytes` to contain the value that was written to `version`, as well as `version` only having one element.

I'm suring I've done this in the browser, is there something about nodejs I should be aware of?

Comment: Uint8Array allocates a new buffer whenever you construct it. They do not share the same memory space/values. If you want a buffer size of 1. Then allocate it with the size of 1. If you want the values, copy the values with a for loop.

Comment: @John That's a crappy difference. If you have a reference, I'd say that's an accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it can share the memory in node if you pass the underlying buffer. So Uint8Array(buffer.buffer) would be the right way to do it: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays

Comment: arg! That's annoyingly simple